# Groupby for values in a list

Tags: pandas

I have a large dataset where I need to perform calculations based on a column called AoIs. For example, for all points where `Name=="P_01"` I want a sum of all durations where `front` is in the `AoIs` column. Then I want to do the same for `side` and `concerns_form`. I have the df grouped by Name, but any contortion of list operations I have tried fails.

Here is a snippet of the data I'm working with:

```
      Name               AoIs  duration
0     P_01                NaN    1704.0
1     P_01                NaN    1654.0
2     P_01                NaN     731.0
3     P_01                NaN    3317.0
4     P_01                NaN     897.0
5     P_01                NaN     773.0
6     P_01                NaN    1155.0
7     P_01       [side,front]    1064.0
8     P_01    [concerns_form]     299.0
9     P_01    [concerns_form]     390.0
```

Here's a snippet of code to create a df like what I'm working with:

```
df = pd.read_json('{"Name":{"0":"P_01","1":"P_01","2":"P_01","3":"P_01","4":"P_01","5":"P_01","6":"P_01","7":"P_01","8":"P_01","9":"P_01","10":"P_01","11":"P_01","12":"P_01","13":"P_01","14":"P_01","15":"P_01","16":"P_01","17":"P_01","18":"P_01","19":"P_01"},"AoIs":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":["front", "side"],"8":["concerns_form","side"],"9":["concerns_form"],"10":["concerns_form"],"11":["concerns_title"],"12":["concerns_form"],"13":["concerns_submit"],"14":["side_nav"],"15":["concerns_title"],"16":["side_nav"],"17":["concerns_form"],"18":["concerns_title"],"19":["concerns_title"]},"duration":{"0":1704.0,"1":1654.0,"2":731.0,"3":3317.0,"4":897.0,"5":773.0,"6":1155.0,"7":1064.0,"8":299.0,"9":390.0,"10":1612.0,"11":1396.0,"12":2236.0,"13":798.0,"14":274.0,"15":182.0,"16":440.0,"17":166.0,"18":382.0,"19":282.0}}')
```

Comment: `from_json` should be `read_json` no?

Answer (score 2):

I would add some new columns and then make some grouping.

```
df['side'] = df['AoIs'].map(str).str.contains('side')
df['front'] = df['AoIs'].map(str).str.contains('front')
df['concerns_form'] = df['AoIs'].map(str).str.contains('concerns_form')
```

end then for example:

```
df[df['side']==True].groupby('Name').sum()
```

Comment: Though a bit slow, one trick to get dummies for all values is `df.AoIs.str.join('*').str.get_dummies(sep='*').astype(bool)`. Then you can concatenate that back to your original

Comment: Yep. I wonder if AoIs colum contains list or just strings. If lists: man can use df['side'] = df['AoIs'].map(lambda row: 'side' in row)

Answer (score 0):

Using a filtered `groupby`:

```
target = 'front'
df[[target in x if isinstance(x,list) else False for x in df.AoIs]].groupby('Name').duration.sum()
```

Output:

```
Name
P_01    1064
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the 'AoIs' column into two columns then you can groupby either or both columns. This also allows you to change your grouping criteria

df[['Right', 'Left']] = df['AoIs'].str.split(',', expand=True)